# Android : GameController support

Tags: android, gamecontroller

Apologies if this is not the place to ask this question.

I have started writing an Android 3D framework where I want to support game controllers / gamepads.  I have added the MOGA SDK but this has got me thinking that I will need to go about adding every game controllers SDK, this seems a little heavy, plus hard to test.

What do other Android Game developers do about this?  Android seems to have a API for USB controllers but not for Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer to this is InputDeviceListener, this seems to be the standard and supports controllers like the Ouya controller right out of the box.

A good sample from GOOGLE can be found here

http://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/compatibility.html